# 2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am try to extract some quotes from  [here](https://www.goodreads.com/quote) using Scrapy but I am running into some kind of problem. here is my code.

```
import scrapy
start_urls=['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes']
for number in range(1,11):
  start_urls.append('https://www.goodreads.com/{}'.format(str(number)))

class quotes(scrapy.Spider):
name='goodreads_quotes'
def start_requests(self):
    urls=start_urls
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)
        
def parse(self,response):
    quotes=response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract()
    for quote in quotes:
        if len(quote)>10:
           yield quote
```

Every time I try to run it in scrapy shell, I get the following error

```
2020-10-16 21:53:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-16 21:53:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 
items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-16 21:53:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-10-16 21:53:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.goodreads.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/7> 
 (referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/2> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/5> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/3> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/6> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/4> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.goodreads.com/1> 
(referer: None)
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 
https://www.goodreads.com/7>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' 
in <GET https://www.goodreads.com/quotes>

2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 
https://www.goodreads.com/9>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-10-16 21:53:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions, that can help me successfully scrape the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error points out, a `parse` function must return a `request`, `item`, or `None`.  It errors because you are trying to return a `str`.  Instead of returning a `str`, you can solve this by creating a class that inherits from `scrapy.Item` and holds the data you want:

```py
# Create a scrapy.Item class which will hold all the scraped data
class Quote(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    # any additional info you want to put in a quote...

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract()
        for quote in quotes:
            if len(quote) > 10:
               # We return a Quote scrapy.Item instead of a string!
               yield Quote(text=quote)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to define the fields. Go to items.py file and paste the code written below inside the class:

```
 quotes = scrapy.Field()
```